# relationship between controller and model emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to ember and I have a few questions about the relationship between the model and controller in ember.js

At first I saw different types of data saving and I'm a little bit confused

```
    var posts = [{
      id: '1',
      title: "Rails is Omakase",
      author: { name: "d2h" },
      date: new Date('12-27-2012')
    };
```

but then I saw things like:

```
    App.Post.FIXTURES = [{
      id: '1',
      title: "Rails is Omakase",
      author: { name: "d2h" },
      date: new Date('12-27-2012')
    };
```

What is the difference?

When do I use an `Ember.ArrayController` vs `Ember.Controller` the difference is not really obvious to me. I think when the model is a list then I have to use `Ember.ArrayController`, but I saw several examples to the contrary?

And how do I bind a model onto my controller? I tried:

model

```
App.AgentenverteilungRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return[{
            TextNr: 'CallcenterPlaetze',
            texte:
                [
                    {
                        sprache: '0',
                        text:"some string",
                        hilfetext: "some string"
                    },{
                        sprache: '1',
                        text:"some string",
                        hilfetext: "some string"
                }],
            value: 10,
            insertattribut: "Textfeld"
        }]
    }
});
```

controller

```
App.AgentverteilungController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ["index"],
    sprachevar: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.index"),
    sprache: 2,

    weiter: function () {
        this.transitionToRoute('bounddefinition')

    }
});
```

I know these are a lot of questions, but I've been looking for 3 days about this shit and I need help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember works perfectly fine with Plain ol JavaScript Objects, which is what this is:

```
var posts = [{
  id: '1',
  title: "Rails is Omakase",
  author: { name: "d2h" },
  date: new Date('12-27-2012')
}];
```

This would be used with Ember Data or Ember Model (two different products for client side record management)

```
App.Post.FIXTURES = [{
  id: '1',
  title: "Rails is Omakase",
  author: { name: "d2h" },
  date: new Date('12-27-2012')
};
```

Controllers in Ember are used in a decorator/proxy pattern.  Meaning they just decorate a model, and proxy gets and sets down to the model itself.  So if your model is a collection, you should use an `ArrayController`.  If it's a single object, you should use `ObjectController`.  If you have no model, you should use `Controller`.

Your route is perfectly find, you should now define that route in the router and transition to it.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('agentenverteilung');
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/madane/1/edit